# Is the QVTD (declarative) plugin eclipse already in a version stable?

Tags: qvtkwidget, qvt

I want to realize a transformation from DMN to BPMN. I think to use the QVTD (declarative) plugin eclipse already but is it in a version stable ?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not. The Oxygen (June 2017) release of QVTc/QVTr is only suitable for research purposes. Lack of support for Overriding is a serious omission. Lack of support for In-place may be a problem. Lack of support for copy (not in the spec) may also be a problem.

Regards

Ed Willink